# Is it possible to deal with concurrency problems for storing ERC-721 metadata?

Tags: storage, erc-721, nft

Regarding ERC-721 metadata, I'm considering storing all the metadata for the NFTs externally. The problem is, because I want to have each NFT be unique, I need to find a way to store which NFTs have already been minted.

I came up with two different possibilities:

- Each time the the data is interacted with and read, it is updated to remove the minted NFT metadata
- Whenever a new token is minted, it adds a unique hash to the contract that represents the new NFT dna. All hashes added to the contract cannot be used again for minting

My question is: how is it possible to deal with concurrency issues for both these scenarios? For example, if two people mint a token at the same time, isn't it possible that both retrieve the same hash before it is written to the contract, hence creating a duplicate?

Is this even an issue or does Ethereum already deal with this?
Thanks.

Comment: More details please // who creates the content? // what kind of content?

Comment: all transactions in Ethereum are processed sequentially so there can't be duplicates. But if you don't change the inputs to the hashing function there will be duplicates of course. You need to guarantee randomness at the input to the hash function

Comment: @Nulik if Ethereum processes transactions sequantially, that should mean that two users interacting with a contract can never read a variable at the same time, is this correct? If that's the case, it would suffice to save a hash representing the NFT in the contract itself. Or no?

Comment: " _two users interacting with a contract can never read a variable at the same time_ " correct

Comment: you also can just assign a sequential number which is much easier and clearer